# Hibernate Criteria Query with Vararg Method

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

The objective is to get certain entities with specific ids. I want to create a vararg method that will take entity ids and return the entity list according to the ids:

```
@Override
public List<Entity> getEntities(long... ids) {

    Session s = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    s.beginTransaction();
    Criteria criteria = s.createCriteria(Entity.class);

    for (long id : ids) {
        // for very id I want to create a Restriction 
        // but Restriction goes like
        //  criteria.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.eq("id", id),Restrictions.eq("id", id)));
    }

    s.getTransaction().commit();
    return null;
}
```

Usage will be:

```
List<Entity> list = getEntities(453,282,781,784);
```

How to create such criteria query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variable number of `OR id = ?` clause is like an IN clause. This is done using the [`Restrictions.in`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#in-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-) method:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("id", ids));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("id", ids));
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("id"));
```

will solve your problem it will return your result in the same order which you passed into varargs